# Express.js: How do I make a GET request with empty parameters?

Tags: javascript, express

I'm building a simple app that returns a JSON object with time information based on the :date parameter in the URI. Currently if the GET request has no parameter, my app.get method isn't called.  However, I want the user to be able to pass an empty string to :date.  Ultimately I want the user to be able to enter '.../api/timestamp' and return a JSON object for the current date/time.  Is this possible?

```js
app.get('/api/timestamp/:date', (req, res, next) =>{
  
  var d = new Date(req.params.date);
  
  if(d instanceof Date && !isNaN(d)){
    let dateStr = d.toUTCString();
    let dateUnix = d.getTime();
    res.json({unix : dateUnix, natural : dateStr});
  }
  else if(req.params.date===''){
    console.log("it's empty");
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make `date` an optional parameter by appending '?'

```
app.get('/api/timestamp/:date?', (req, res, next) =>{
....
```

and inside the function, you can check if a date is passed or not.